# How can we annotate an unicode character in uima ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

How can we annotate an unicode character in uima ruta:
 For Example: I want to mark this text(Paris: Ã‰ditions Robert Laffont).So I used the following rule.

```
DECLARE CITY;
CW COLON CW+{->MARK(CITY,1,3)};
```

But the text covered upto Paris: Ã. Is there any way to solve this problem. Awaiting for the answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have faced the similar problem for EN DASH (unicode=â€“). I used  SW SPECIAL+{->MARK(HYPHEN_UNICODE,1,2)};  So that problem is solved. Is that the only way to solve the problem. Orelse there's any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all about he definition of the lexer which creates the token class annotations of ruta (W, CW, SPECIAL ...).

The rule `CW COLON CW+{->MARK(CITY,1,1)};` creates an annotation of the type `CITY` for the text span `Paris` regardless of the unicode character.

The last rule element `CW+` matches on `Ã` since this is annotated with a CW, but stops there since `‰` is not a CW but a SPECIAL.

There are different ways to avoid this problem. My advice would be that you should rely on a different type of annotation for your rules. The job of the lexer annotations of ruta is to create minimal annotations. They do not define tokens in general.

You could maybe use something like this (or use an actual tokenizer for better performance):

```
DECLARE CITY;
DECLARE Token;

RETAINTYPE(SPACE);
(W (SPECIAL? W)*){-> Token};
RETAINTYPE;

Token COLON Token+{->MARK(CITY,1,1)};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for your reply. I had a doubt in this rule Line{-REGEXP("CORA:.*") -> MARK(Reference)}; What  CORA:.* means

Comment: Can you briefly explain about the Html annotator, Html converter and TEIViewWriter with some examples.Because I tried this but I received some error messages.

Comment: Explaining with examples is rather problematic in this comment section. Best, ask this on the UIMA user mailing list (or create a new question here on stackoverflow).

Comment: The HtmlAnnotator creates annotations for HTML and XML tags/elements. The HtmlConverter removes all HTML/XML tags, stores the resulting text in a new view and recalculates the offsets of the annotations. The TEIViewWriter is just a ViewWriter with a specific type system, which copies a specific view to a new CAS and stores it. Together, these components are able to convert a TEI text to plain text with annotations for the xml markup.